# Retrieve a change set from scratch org using sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, ant, change-set, scratch-org

I am trying to bundle up certain metadata in a change set in my scratch org. Is there a way to pull that using sfdx? I am having trouble finding the appropriate command in the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to create a change set in my scratch org and put the metadata I wanted to retrieve from the scratch org.

I managed to pull that change set the same way one pulls a package:

`sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r retrieval -p NameOfChangeSet -u core`

Where `retrieval` is the name of the folder the metadata gets retrieved to and `NameOfChangeSet` is the name of the change set.

Comment: Curiously, I couldn't find this usage in the documentation. I wonder if it's actually supported. Be aware, however, that change sets can implicitly miss data, so if you use it, you risk having an incomplete package.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. How can they miss data? The problem I was experiencing was that no matter what I couldn't get the Create->Packages to show up. That's why I had to go the change set route.

Comment: Sandboxes should have both Change Sets and Packages, while Scratch Orgs should have only Packages. Change Sets can miss data if you don't include it. For example, let's say you select a VF page, but forget to choose the class for the page's controller. When you retrieve it, you will get only the page, not the class, thus be unable to deploy the change to a new org where the class doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will play around with it more next time I have to do this again!

Comment: As of June 2023 this is still working. Able to retrieve change set components from the sfdx command, although it's returned in a zip file. I tried using the `--unzip` parameter but it didn't work for me.