# Unable to deploy change set to production

Tags: apex, deployment, change-set, api-version, deployment-api

After the new realease our developer sandbox changed its API version to 52.0 but or production org still at 51.0 .

When we try to send our change set to procution org, we keep receving this error message: "This change set requires the "52.0" or later platform version.
One or more of the listed organizations is on a version incompatible with this change set. You can only select an organization for upload that is running the required version or later."

We checked the API version in everything on the changeset and there is nothing with API version 52.0

Any ideias?

Comment: It doesn't matter if any components are in the newest version, Change Sets cannot deploy to "older" orgs. You'll have to wait until Production updates, or you can [retrieve via sfdx](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/232584/2984) and then deploy.

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't think that's fully true - just yesterday I deployed change sets from a Summer 21 sandbox to Spring 21 production.  I think it depends on what you're trying to deploy (eg. documentation for Experience Cloud sites explicitly says you can't deploy a site from newer to older).

Comment: If you have already uploaded a changeset to latest release org and then try to upload the same changeset to older release one, it also give sthe same error. I guess the first upload locks the version number.